# Using Windows powershell, how can I delete all strings directly in between ";" or "," and "false"?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have

```
598842,3605false;3605true;36054true;36054true;360true;360false;36054true
598842, 3605true;36054true;36054true;360true;360false;36054true
```

I want to turn it into

```
598842, 3605true;36054true;36054true;360true;36054true
598842, 3605true;36054true;36054true;360true;36054true
```

Pathetic attempts below.

```
(Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv)  -Replace '.*?(\"totalCount\":)', '' | Out-File -FilePath actpageline.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv)  -Replace '.*?(\"false;\":)', '' | Out-File -FilePath actpageline.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv)  -Replace '\",\".*?(\"false;\":)', '' | Out-File -FilePath actpageline.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv)  -Replace '.*?(\"false;\":)', '' | Out-File -FilePath actpageline.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII
    [regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv), '(?s); \[false]', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '' }) | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    [regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv), '(?s);\[false]', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '' }) | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    [regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv), '(?s);\[false]', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '' }) | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    [regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv), ',(?s)\"[false]\"', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '' }) | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    [regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv), '(?s): \[.+?\r?\n        \]', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '[\r\n\"]' }) | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    [regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv), '(?s)\[.+?\r?\n\]', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '' }) | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    [regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv), '(?s)false;\[.+?\r?\n\]', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '' }) | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    [regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv), '(?s)false;.+?\r?\n\', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '' }) | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    [regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv), '(?s)false;.+?\r?\n', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '' }) | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    [regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv), '(?s)false;.+?', { param($match) $match.Value -replace '' }) | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(?s)(?<=;.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(?)(?<=;.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo2.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.s)(?<=;.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(?,)(?<=;.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(?.)(?<=;.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.)(?<=;.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.)(?<=,.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.)(?<=,.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII;(Get-Content -Raw .\noo.csv) -replace 'true','' | Out-File noo2.csv;
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.)(?<=,.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII;(Get-Content -Raw .\noo.csv) -replace 'true','' | Out-File noo2.csv;(Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace 'true','' | Out-File actsnotrue.csv
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.)(?<=;.*?)[\r\n"](?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.)(?<=;.*?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.)(?<=true;.*?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.)(?<=;.*?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.+?)(?<=;.*?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.+?)(?<=,.+?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.*?)(?<=,.*?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(?<=,.*?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.*?)(?<=;.*?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.*?)(?<=;.*?)(?=.*?false)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.*?)(?<=;.*?)(?=false)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.)(?<=;)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.?)(?<=;)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(.*?)(?<=;)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '(?<=;.*?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '.(?<=;.*?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
    (Get-Content -Raw .\actswithpeople.csv) -replace '.*?(?<=;.*?)(?=.*?false;)' | Out-File -FilePath noo.csv -Force -Encoding ASCII
```

I didn't save the output of every one. I thought this was a simple one I could crack, but 3 hours later, I was wrong, it isn't. Please help.

Comment: Does the CSV file have a header row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just this:

```
'
598842,3605false;3605true;36054true;36054true;360true;360false;36054true
598842, 3605true;36054true;36054true;360true;360false;36054true
' -replace '\d+false;' -replace ', |,', ', '

# Results
<#
598842, 3605true;36054true;36054true;360true;36054true
598842, 3605true;36054true;36054true;360true;36054true
#>
```

Comment: What if the `*false` value is at the end of the line?

Comment: @zett42 Then you could split the raw string into single lines and add an `-replace ';\d+false$'`  ;-)

Comment: @mklement0 Learned something new from you today again. Thanks. ;-) But wouldn't the simple version leave the last semikolon untouched?

Comment: If I use the code from postanotes answer, move the `;360false` to the end of the first line and run it with the pattern `'\d+false;?'` I have a semikolon at the end of the first line. If I use the pattern `'(?m)\d+false(?:;|$)'` it does not remove the  `;360false` at all. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: You're correct, @Olaf - I got myself confused by thinking that a _trailing_ `;` needs removal, whereas it is the _leading_ separator that must be removed; please see my answer.

Comment: @mklement0 I actually like that a little bit that even you still get confused sometimes.  ;-) :-)

Comment: @Olaf :) .........

Answer (score 1):

A generalized solution that also handles removal of *trailing* `...false` fields correctly.

```bash
# Note the trailing ";99999false"
$str = @'
598842,3605false;3605true;36054true;36054true;360true;360false;36054true;99999false
598842, 3605true;36054true;36054true;360true;360false;36054true
'@

# Result matches the expected output in the question.
$str  -replace '[,;] ?\d+false' -replace '(?m)(\d+)[,;] ?', '$1, '
```

- The first `-replace` operation removes all `...false` fields including their *preceding* separator (`,` or `;`, optionally followed by a space).
- The second `-replace` ensures that the *first* separator is a `,`, followed by a space.
- Inline regex option `(?m)` (the multi-line option, which makes `^` and `$` match the start and end of *each line*) is only necessary if the input is a single, *multi-line* string rather than an *array* of strings.